# mongoose - how to query records of a collection which combine with an ObjectId-to-Number Map from another collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the schema below:

`schema/collectible.ts`: The items that can be collected

```js
const Collectible = new mongoose.schema({
  title: String,
  image: String
})

new Collectible({ title: 'ABC', image: 'ABC.png' }).save()
new Collectible({ title: 'DEF', image: 'DEF.png' }).save()
```

`schema/inventory.ts`: Storing a `Map` that represent the number of `Collectible` that an user owned

```js
const Inventory = new mongoose.schema({
  owner: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  items: {
    type: Map,
    of: Number
  }
})


new Inventory({ 
  owner: ObjectId(USER_ID), 
  items: {
    "abc_objectid_str": 2,
    "def_objectid_str": 4,
  } 
}).save()
```

The goal of the query result is

```
[
  { title: 'ABC', image: 'ABC.png', amount: 2 },
  { title: 'DEF', image: 'DEF.png', amount: 4 },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$lookup` pipeline with `$objectToArray` and `$reduce`:

```
db.collectible.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "inventory",
      let: {title: {$toLower: "$title"}},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {owner: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")}},
        {$project: {_id: 0, data: {$objectToArray: "$items"}}},
        {$set: {
            data: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$data",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                  $add: [
                    {$cond: [
                        {$eq: [{$first: {$split: ["$$this.k", "_"]}}, "$$title"]},
                        "$$this.v",
                        0
                    ]},
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "countData"
    }
  },
  {$project: {_id: 0, image: 1, title: 1, amount: {$first: "$countData.data"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2z82PfkCrqd)